# Crashlytics found an invalid API key - AndroidStudio build

Tags: android, android-studio, crashlytics

I saw all other questions, but none of accepted answers is working for me.

By following integration steps found here https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/integrate I have created crashlytics.properties file in module root. File is filled with apiKey and apiSecret values found in my newly created twitter application.

Error occurr on project build. I am using AndroidStudio 1.0

This is my error:

```
ERROR - Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Crashlytics found an invalid API key: REAL_APIKEY_VALUE. 
Check the Crashlytics plugin to make sure that the application has been added successfully! 
Contact support@fabric.io for assistance.
```

Comment: I would just use the crashlytics plug in for AS and just let it create all of that for you.

Comment: @warl0ck08: Thats what i did finally and luckily it did good job, without errors. As Misha (in comments below stated) it does not work always.

Comment: I'm getting this only when running Instrument tests.... Any ideas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Works fine added this on fabric.properties like this:

```
# Fabric properties file: app/fabric.properties
apiSecret=xx68f6074dxxxxxc11dxxx97c172e8ebf0
apiKey=xxxe76c4xxxx97e8cxxxx0135e9d46f5a2xxx
```

Add on .gitignore (for open source projects)

**REMOVE** entry on AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
    android:value="xxx6c41xxx6ec601xxxd4xxxa2" />
```

Oficial documentation: https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/settings/working-in-teams.html

Comment: I am going to trust you and accept this answer. After this question, I have integrated Crashlytics numerous times with usage of Fabric plugin in Android Studio and it works as expected. So I would suggest the same to you. In my opinion that should be the only and right way to do integration.

Comment: right now the two ways are valid implementations. But for continuous integration, it implementation is only way. The basic config from plugin works fine, but for CI and OpenSource projects we need it

Comment: The Android plugin didn't work for me. Also, in iOS had to manually add the pods as the app didn't recognize that the project uses CocoaPods (I opened the workspace file).

Comment: what if my project is using firebase? as fabric is merged with firebase

Answer (score 60):

You just forgot to add one line, in app-level gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this happens because when you are adding firebase:crashlytics, firebase document not have this line. so you need to add it manually. see this is firebase:crashlytics document photo.[image: Check This Image]

Comment: This is the answer

Answer (score 46):

This happened to me when I updated Android Studio from `3.2` to `3.3`, to fix it I just updated the

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

And it worked again

Comment: Updating to google-services 4.2.0 also fixed it for me

Comment: Downgrading to classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' will also work.

Comment: The problem still exists on `com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0`

Answer (score 17):

I also experienced this issue and it took a while for me to realize I forgot adding the following line into the `app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

After adding it, it started working like a charm even without `<meta-data>` in manifest and/or `app/fabric.properties` file.

Comment: For me keeping the <meta-data> failed compilation (kept getting a message of an invalid key) so i had to remove it.

Comment: This is the exact answer as google forgot this step in online documentation for firebase

Answer (score 9):

Add the below line in app/build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Clean The Project and Run.

Answer (score 6):

after adding file fabric.properties, getting error as below.

**Crashlytics found an invalid API key: null.
Check the Crashlytics plugin to make sure that the application has been 
added successfully! 
Contact support@fabric.io for assistance.**

We need to register app and verify SHA-1 for same.
**Add firebase:** add google-services.json file from firebase console to your /app folder of your application.(follow steps given by Firebase Console-> **Add Firebase to your Android app** )
It's not giving error now

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta-data android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey" 
           android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

Add this one on Android manifest.xml
here you get the api key 
https://www.fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

Answer (score 0):

If someone is using crashlytics with Android dynamic features module, make sure your fabric and google-services plugins are applied only in your app module. In my case that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the below dependency at project build.gradle from :

classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.**1**.0"

to

classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.**2**.0"

has solved the problem for me.