# Getting Crashlytics Issue after Gradle update

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

Getting below error after just updating `Gradle` plug in Android

```
Crashlytics found an invalid API key: null. 
Check the Crashlytics plugin to make sure that the application has been added successfully! 
Contact support@fabric.io for assistance.
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: The link will helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472452/crashlytics-found-an-invalid-api-key-androidstudio-build

Comment: It's not a duplicate at all. It's the same error but on a completely different platform. (Google Firebase Crashlytics vs Fabric Crashlytics)

Suffering from the same issue just now.. hoping to find a solution.

Comment: For those who are still looking for a solution, here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52614015/invalid-crashlytics-api-key-error-when-upgrading-to-android-gradle-plugin-3-3-0).

Answer (score 0):

you have to add meta-data into menifest file with correct API key

Ex:-

```
 <manifest 
 <application
 <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="xxxx.......xx"
            />

 </application>
 </manifest>
```

just like this...

Comment: But I am using with Firebase. Issue happened after just updated Gradle plug in classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha10'
​
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10-all.zip

Comment: @RavikumarS I had the same error with that Android Plugin for Gradle dependency (3.3.0-alpha10). Downgrading to 3.2.0-rc03 fixed it.