# cordova plugin firebase compilation issue

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create an Ionic application with firebase native plugin.

First step I create my ionic app :
`ionic start`

Then I add firebase plugin:
`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase
npm install @ionic-native/firebase`

After that I try to add android platform :
`ionic cordova build android`

And I have this error :

```
> Task :app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug FAILED
ERROR - Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Crashlytics found an invalid API key: null.
```

My plugin list `cordova plugin list` :

```
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.5 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
```

If I use android studio, I have the same error :
Crashlytics found an invalid API key: null.

So I used this post : [Crashlytics found an invalid API key - AndroidStudio build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472452/crashlytics-found-an-invalid-api-key-androidstudio-build)

After that I get this error : error: cannot find symbol class NotificationManagerCompat.
So I have added the dependency `implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.+'` to builde.gradle of my application.

But I'm still facing 2 errors :

```
#android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/firebase/FirebasePlugin.java
error: method getByteArray in class FirebaseRemoteConfig cannot be applied to given types;
required: String
found: String,String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

```
#android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/firebase/FirebasePluginInstanceIDService.java
error: cannot find symbol class FirebaseInstanceIdService
error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

How I can get an ionic app working with firebase (firestore, auth and cloud messaging) ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I also remember having endless issues with those Firebase related plugins, but I finally managed to make them work with `cordova@7.1.0` and `cordova-android@6.3.0`. If I remember correctly, I solved one of the problems by [switching the **Gradle** version](https://www.andreszsogon.com/upgrading-gradle-version-for-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/) to 4.1.

I have only the [cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication) plugin and it depends on [cordova-support-google-services](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-support-google-services), which you don't seem to have installed. You should double-check if your plugin requires it.